# posting json with <br /> it breaks

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net

Why if I add a `<br />` to the "name" property does the ajax not post to the code behind, but if I don't add it then it works fine?

the JSON array below is auto generated like this:

```
//        var tableOBJ = [];
//
//
//        $("table tr").each(function () {
//
//            var r = new rowOBJ(

//                $(this).find('td').eq(0).val(),
//                $(this).find('td').eq(1).text()
//                                   
//                                    );
//
//            tableOBJ.push(r);
//
//        });



var myJS = 
[
{"name":"d <br />","surname":"cxzc"},
{"name":"d ","surname":"cxzc"},
{"name":"d ","surname":"cxzc"},
{"name":"d ","surname":"cxzc"},
{"name":"d ","surname":"cxzc"}
];


 var gg = { "myText": JSON.stringify(myJS) };

 //var gg = JSON.stringify({ "myText": myJS }); //this does not work either, code-behind does not see it at all






        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.aspx",
            data: gg,
            success: function (data) {
                //pass

            },
            error: function () {
                //fail

            }
        });

    });
```

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim s As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("myText")

End Sub
```

Comment: Escape those `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` character codes.

Comment: but how do I do that autromaticallty as thwe JSON string array  is auto generated

Comment: Javascript has some pretty useful string manipulation functions, you could find and replace them all and _then_ JSON encode them.

Comment: "Handles Me.Load" made me giggle

Comment: how do I encode this $(this).find('td').eq(0).val()  because this did not work  -- > var string = $('textarea').val();
var encoded = $('<div/>').text(string).html();

Comment: I am thinking you should not use .html(), because you are introducing an XSS vulnerability. Can you change it to .text()?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to encode the html or change the configuration to allow that type of request.
Asp.net is preventing html from being accepted in a request as a security measure.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest.aspx#Y0)

```
<ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("validateRequest", DefaultValue := True)> _
```

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax method thinks it sends HTML data by making an intelligent guess.  So if you add

```
dataType:'json'
```

to the list of parameters of the ajax call it should solve your issue.